# Parando um router quando seu router filho termina

Tags: scala, akka

Tenho um `Ator` que seria o `Root` e esse ator `Root` possui um router com 5 instancias, e esse mesmo router possui também um router com 5 instancias. Como posso parar `ArquivoParaProcessar` e avisar para o `Root` que todos as instancias de `arquivoRouter` pararam?

```java
class Root extends Actor {

  val arquivoRouter = context.actorOf(Props(new ArquivoParaProcessar(agregadorDeLinha)).withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 5)))

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {

    case "init" => {
      context.watch(arquivoRouter)
      arquivoRouter ! new Servidor(Servidor1)
      arquivoRouter ! new Servidor(Servidor2)
      arquivoRouter ! new Servidor(Servidor3)
      arquivoRouter ! new Servidor(Servidor4)
    }

    case Terminated(corpse) => {
      context.system.shutdown()
    }
  }
}

class ArquivoParaProcessar(agregadorDeLinha: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  val linhaRouter = context.actorOf(Props(new LinhaActor(agregadorDeLinha)).withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 5)))

  context.watch(linhaRouter)

  override def receive = {
    case Servidor(caminho) => {
      for {
        arquivo <- new File(caminho).listFiles()
        if (arquivo.isFile)
        linha <- Source.fromFile(arquivo).getLines()
      } yield linhaRouter ! new LinhaParaProcessar(linha)

      linhaRouter ! PoisonPill
    }

    case Terminated(corpse) => {
         println("terminou")
         context stop self
    }
}

class LinhaActor(agregadorLinha: ActorRef) extends Actor
  //mais código
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, vamos entender a sua hierarquia:

```
Root -> arquivoRouters -> "arquivoRouttees" (5) -> linhaRouter -> "linhaRoutees" (5)
```

Como você está usando roteadores, você tem atores intermediários que representam esses caras. O seu `context.watch` está observando esses atores intermediários, e não os routees.

Ou seja, o que você quer fazer é mais complicado do que parece. Coincidentemente, na versão 2.3.2 do Akka, o `RoundRobinRouter` foi depreciado, e a nova forma de criar esses roteadores faz algo que pode ser útil para você: o primeiro exemplo da documentação mostra o uso do `context.watch` sendo aplicado a cada `routee` individualmente. Essa página pode te ajudar:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/scala/routing.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar daquele modo e respondo aqui como ficou.